# White line in mobile website

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am seeing a white line in mobile website (testing with Google Chrome / Safari). There is a background image repeated on the x-axis with the background color for the element set the same.

Also there are no borders involved with this div. The line is on the top of the #header div.

[image]

```
#header {
    height: 130px;
    line-height: 112px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f6a72d url('images/bg.png') repeat-x top;
}
```

view site: http://www.no11.ee/ooker

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is there a public URL to this site? If so, care to share?

Comment: The issue here is that you are not sharing a working example. Try to reproduce the problem in a stacksnippet or in a jsfiddle.net to allow us to debug it.

Comment: Hi, updated the post with link

Comment: I think this is caused by `border-top: 1px solid #F8A80F;` in CSS `#header` the orange hue of that border is a bit lighter than the background's orange.

Comment: Hi, removed this. It was for testing purpose but doesn't resolve it.

Comment: @user3615851 I don't see any other white line beside that.. on what mobile have you tested?

Comment: Iphone 6 - chrome and safari both. Iphone 5s - safari. You may want to zoom in on the spot shown on the image for better view. Also visible on android device (can not specify the device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved with adding margin-bottom:-1px to the div.

Comment: worked for me - weird is that this was only necessary fro chrome for android, not for desktop