# White line appears on chrome mobile when two images are stacked one below the other

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

For devices with DPR such as 2.625(one plus 5), there is a white line which appears on chrome mobile browser when images are stacked one below the other.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxXbRo

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            .img {
                display: block;
                width: 412px;
                height: 183px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="https://dummyimage.com/412x183/2c38bd/000000">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="https://dummyimage.com/412x183/2c38bd/000000">
    </body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNduB.png)

Comment: Hey Nimish,
welcome to SO, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311124/white-line-in-mobile-website

Comment: Out of curiosity: Have you tried requesting an image double the size and scale it down by 50%?

Comment: Also, try messing around with [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).

Comment: @maryisdead I tried both the approaches no luck. The issue is not happening in firefox browser. Probably something messed up with chrome browser. Needed a workaround to resolve this issue.